# Powershell Webclient Giberish from Piratebay

Tags: powershell, encoding, webclient

I've got a script that scraps ThePiratebay for me and gets me back whats on the webpage, it worked fine for a long time and recenly something must have changed on their encoding and now I'm banging my head against a wall trying to figure it out.  Below is an example so anyone can see the giberish it returns.

I've tried adding in the encoding here with no such luck:

```
$WC.Headers.Add('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate,sdch')
$WC.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

Here is the code that will return the giberish:

```
$WC = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$URL = "http://thepiratebay.se/search/New%20Girl%20s03e23/0/7/0"
$WC.DownloadString($URL)
```

This used to get me a string, now I just get an assortment of characters.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This works fine for me, without changing the headers or encoding. Could you explain what you mean by an assortment of characters? Perhaps posting an example response.

Comment: I tested it again on Saturday and it seems to be fine now, but all last week I got symboles and random characters. My guess is that they made a change to their backend and etither made another change or reverted it. Thanks for double checking for me and if I see it again I'll be sure to report it back.

Comment: @Banford Now its back to the strange characters.  Here's an example let me know what you think. 
`Hå”¨ÑÊs×ui$q Ç$ö0K▲æÆXSìéÑ3↕ÇÀó‰♦—☺¸f†♥↕–JÑéÿM`

Comment: I'm still getting this off and on with the above.  I tried on another site today (kickass.to) and I saw the same thing.  It seems very random and I can't seem to nail down what is giving me the huge output of weird symbols.  I think I have a lack of understanding of the headers or decompression with the Webclient, any help is appreciated.

Some more code that gave me odd output:
$WC = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$URL = "http://kickass.to/usearch/drunk%20history%20s02e01"
$WC.DownloadString($URL)